# Only Single cell expands at a time in UITableViewCell in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am implementing an expandable and collapsable table cell on the click of a button in the custom table cell. I have tried the following code but it expands only single cell at a time. That is if I click a cell it expands but if I click on another cell it expands and the already expanded cell collapses.

```
var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?

func configure(cell: MyProposalCustomCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let pool = myProposalsDetails[indexPath.row]
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell.proposalNumber.text = pool.proposalNumber
    cell.pickUpLocation.text = pool.pickupLocation
    cell.dropLocation.text = pool.dropLocation
    cell.journeyType.text = pool.journeyType
    cell.firstShiftOnwardTime.text = pool.firstPickupTime
    cell.firstShiftReturnTime.text = pool.firstEndTime
    if let numberOfInterests = pool.noOfInterest {
        cell.numberOfInterest.text = String(numberOfInterests)
    }

    if let operatingDays = pool.operatingDays {
        cell.daysOfOperation.attributedText = Utility.getProposedOperatingDays(operatingDays: operatingDays)
    }
    cell.expandCollapse.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.expandCollapse.addTarget(self, action: #selector(expandTableCell(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    if selectedIndexPath == indexPath {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            cell.backgroundColor = CustomColor.selectedBackground.color
            cell.bottomView.backgroundColor = CustomColor.selectedBackground.color
            cell.expandCollapse.setImage(UIImage(named: "collapse_arrow.png"), for: .normal)
            if let proposedStartDate = pool.startDate {
                let propStartDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: proposedStartDate)
                cell.proposedStartDate.text = Utility.getFormattedDate(date: propStartDate)
                cell.proposedStartDateTxt.text = NSLocalizedString("Proposed start date", comment: "")
            }
            cell.returnTime.alpha = 0.0
        })
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            cell.expandCollapse.setImage(UIImage(named: "down_arrow.png"), for: .normal)
            cell.proposedStartDateTxt.text = NSLocalizedString("Journey type", comment: "")
            cell.bottomView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            cell.proposedStartDate.text = pool.journeyType
            cell.returnTime.isHidden = false
        })
    }
}
```

This is the expandable button action:

```
func expandTableCell(sender: UIButton) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    if selectedIndexPath == indexPath {
        selectedIndexPath = nil
    } else {
        let previousSelIndex = selectedIndexPath
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        if let previousSelectedIndexPath = previousSelIndex {
            if tripStatus.tripType != .splitShift {
                if let previousSelectedCell = myProposals.cellForRow(at: previousSelectedIndexPath)   as? MyProposalCustomCell {
                    configure(cell: previousSelectedCell, forRowAtIndexPath: previousSelectedIndexPath)
                }
            } else {
                if let previousSelectedCell = myProposals.cellForRow(at: previousSelectedIndexPath)   as? MyProposalSplitShiftCell {
                    configureSplitShift(cell: previousSelectedCell, forRowAtIndexPath: previousSelectedIndexPath)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    updateSelectedCell(indexPath: indexPath)
    myProposals.beginUpdates()
    myProposals.endUpdates()
}

func updateSelectedCell(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tripStatus.tripType != .splitShift {
        if let selectedCell = myProposals.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyProposalCustomCell {
            configure(cell: selectedCell, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        }
    } else {
        if let selectedCell = myProposals.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyProposalSplitShiftCell {
            configureSplitShift(cell: selectedCell, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let headingHeight: CGFloat = 128
    let detailsHeight: CGFloat = 80
    let splitShiftDetailsHeight: CGFloat = 215

    switch tripStatus.tripType {

    case .oneWayTrip, .roundTrip:
        if selectedIndexPath != nil && indexPath.compare(selectedIndexPath! as IndexPath) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame {
            return headingHeight + detailsHeight
        }
        return headingHeight

    case .splitShift:
        if selectedIndexPath != nil && indexPath.compare(selectedIndexPath! as IndexPath) == ComparisonResult.orderedSame {
            return headingHeight + splitShiftDetailsHeight
        }
        return headingHeight
    }
}
```

I want to get multiple cells to be expanded. How to achieve this?

Comment: if satisfactory answer is that somebody will program it for you, I'm afraid you will not get the satisfactory answer here.. how to use array? same way you now use a single variable, just now you will be remembering multiple selected cells that have to be expanded, instead of a single one. If you don't know how arrays work, please, refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105

Answer (score 0):

This is very straight forward, instead of taking **selectedIndexPath** try to keep one variable in your custom UITableViewCell class something like,

```
class ExpandableCell: UITableViewCell {

    var isExpanded: Bool = false

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func moreButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    }
}
```

And then try to toggle the **isExpanded** boolean flag, and try to perform your `func updateSelectedCell(indexPath: IndexPath) {}` action.

Comment: Please post the full answer it will be helpful for me